# How to use the distinct and count function to get distinct users and number of messages sent

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is this table I'm currently trying to make a query on. the data looks like as follows:

```
--------------------------------
| Message_Time | User | Message|
--------------------------------
|y-m-d H:M:S   |User1 | msg-body
|y-m-d H:M:S   |User1 | msg-body
|y-m-d H:M:S   |User1 | msg-body
|y-m-d H:M:S   |User2 | msg-body
|y-m-d H:M:S   |User2 | msg-body
```

I'm trying to select the users and count the amount of messages sent by each individual user

I've tried to select from this db and do a distinct on the User column and count on the Message column but i keep getting an error. I'm sure I'm not approaching it the correct way.

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(USER) AS [User_ID], COUNT(Message) AS [Messages_Sent] 
FROM [dbo].[Table]
```

This is my desired output:

```
--------------------------
| User_ID | Messages_Sent|
--------------------------
|User1    |       3      | 
|User2    |       2      |
```

But unfortunately this is the error that occurs:

`Operand data type ntext is invalid for count operator.`

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL? Please be careful when choosing tags.

Comment: The (n)text datatype has been deprecated for close to 15 years now in favor of (n)varchar(max).

Comment: @malmonte . . . The syntax and question look like SQL Server.  Please tag your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT USER AS [User_ID], COUNT(*) AS [Messages_Sent] 
FROM [dbo].[Table]
GROUP BY USER;
```

Presumably, `Message` is never `NULL`, so this does the same thing.

By the way, replace `text` with `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)`.  `text` is deprecated.  As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) states:

> IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much. I also made the changes to the tags you suggested. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

use  group by for aggreagated

```
SELECT USER AS [User_ID], COUNT(*) AS [Messages_Sent] 
FROM [dbo].[Table]
GROUP BY USER
```

this return not null rows

the aggreation function always  return distinct result

```
SELECT USER AS [User_ID], COUNT(message) AS [Messages_Sent] 
FROM [dbo].[Table]
GROUP BY USER
```

this return the count  where column value is not null

Comment: This won't actually stop the error the OP is getting, as `Message` is an `ntext`.

Comment: count(column)  return the number of not value in column  ..the error  is related  at the missing  group  by

Comment: You had `COUNT(Message)` before, which was the reason for the error the OP was getting.

Comment: answer updated with both ...  count(*) is for not null rows .. count(message)  is not null null message value  https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Fix your data type, and then your query will work fine:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Table] ALTER COLUMN Message nvarchar(MAX);
```

As mentioned in the comments `ntext` has been deprecated for years, it's past time to stop using it and use the correct one.